# how to solve error: conversion from type 'dbnull' to type 'string' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I am using i code but i had error:**conversion from type 'dbnull' to type 'string' is not valid**

Public Function Get_Talukwise_Details()

```
        Dim table1 As New DataTable
        table1.Columns.Add("Taluk", GetType(String))
        table1.Columns.Add("EmpScheme", GetType(String))

        iStr1 = Split(Trim(cmbCompCode.Text), "|")
        iStr2 = Split(Trim(cmbLocCode.Text), "|")

        Dim Add_Where_Cont As String
        Add_Where_Cont = ""
        Add_Where_Cont &= " Where CompCode='" & Trim(iStr1(0)) & "'"
        Add_Where_Cont &= " and LocCode='" & Trim(iStr2(0)) & "'"

        SSQL = ""
        SSQL &= "select Taluk, "
        SSQL &= "isnull(SUM(CASE EmpScheme WHEN 'left' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'') as Emp_left,"
        SSQL &= "isnull(SUM(CASE EmpScheme WHEN 'complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'') as Emp_scheme,"
        SSQL &= "isnull( SUM(CASE EmpScheme WHEN 'non-scheme' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),'') as Emp_Non_Scheme"
        SSQL &= " from employee_mst"
        SSQL &= " " & Add_Where_Cont
        SSQL = SSQL & "group by Taluk"

        mDataSet = ReturnMultipleValue(SSQL)

        For iRow = 0 To mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            table1.Rows.Add( _
                            Trim(mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)("Taluk")), _
                            Trim(mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)("EmpScheme")))

        Next
        Return table1
    End Function
```

please any one can help me...,

**error message:** conversion from type 'dbnull' to type 'string' is not valid

**error line:**

```
  table1.Rows.Add( _
                                Trim(mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)("Taluk")), _
                                Trim(mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)("EmpScheme")))
```

Comment: what line is the error pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting null value to string. first see if your query gives correct results.check condition as 
if not isdbnull("Taluk")=true then 
.
.
.
Your code
.
.

End if

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
table1.Rows.Add( _
                            Trim(iif(isdbnull(mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)("Taluk")), "", mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)("Taluk"))), _
                            Trim(iif(isdbnull(mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)("EmpScheme")), "", mDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)("EmpScheme"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either check for `Taluk` being `IsDbNull` in your VB.NET code or it could be more appropriate to return an empty string from the query (as you have done with `ISNULL` in the query already):

```
SSQL &= "SELECT COALESCE(Taluk, ''), "
' ....
SSQL = SSQL & "group by COALESCE(Taluk, '')"
```

Perhaps a `NULL` `Taluk` is a rogue value in the database.